# RDLC doesn't break line when the word is too long

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc, line-breaks

I have a RDLC Report with a Tablix. The Tablix has a Row bound to a DataSet.  The Row has a Textbox with a width of 400px.

If you get a long string with spaces from the DataSet, it will behave as expected and break the string in new lines, making the textbox grow vertically.  The problem happens when you get a long string without spaces from the DataSet, the string doesn't break when it reaches the end of the textbox. Instead, the textbox will grow horizontally to fit the string.

How can I break the string and prevent the Textbox from growing horizontally?

---

After consulting [How to maintain long text inside RDLC report column ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32594761/how-to-maintain-long-text-inside-rdlc-report-column)

- Counting the characters doesn't solve the problem: the data is coming from a database, so it can be virtually anything. And since I'm not using a console font, the size of the letters will not be the same, so the number of '@' that fit in a space is not the same number of 'i'.
- CanGrow Property is bound to the TextBox: So even though you can select a column and set CanGrow to true, it will not set the Column itself to stop growing horizontally, it will just set all selected Textboxes 'CanGrow' property to False.
- CanGrow Property only prevent the row from growing vertically: Even if you click on a Column. CanGrow Property only affects Height.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to maintain long text inside RDLC report column ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32594761/how-to-maintain-long-text-inside-rdlc-report-column)

Comment: No, CanGrow only works vertically, and System.Environment.NewLine is just useless, because my data comes from a database, and I can't just "trial and error" it.

Comment: Wait what... you want the column / textbox to grow horizontally? Or should it grow in both ways? Or should it simply not grow and only show the text in the given space? I read it as you wanted a fixed width and make it grow vertically. You can get the dataset, alter it and then add it to the report, that shouldn't be a problem. And you could do trial and error, just check how many "@" characters fit in the 400px and add line-breaks there....

Comment: The textbox is currently growing horizontally. I want the textbox to grow vertically. The "CanGrow" attribute prevents the textbox from growing vertically, that's why it doesn't solve my problem. And no, trial and error will not solve because my data is not only '@'s, the amount of '@' that fit in the 400px is way less than the amount of 'i', so counting the characters is a terrible solution.

Comment: If you read the answer carefully on the other post you'll see that this is exactly what you're looking for. Place the textbox inside a Tablix and set the **column** `CanGrow` on **False** and the **row** `CanGrow` on **True**. This will make the textbox grow vertically. I don't see a problem. And as far as your other remarks go, you could've been more detailed in describing your problem.

Comment: the CanGrow attribute is textbox-bound, not column-bound or row-bound.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is where you're wrong. Take a look at this MSDN tutorial: [Change Row Height or Column Width (Report Builder and SSRS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239377.aspx). Look at the part that says `To prevent a row from automatically expanding vertically`, now you can apply the exact same method to the column preventing it from growing horizontally (ofc you must allow the row to grow vertically then). Just as I tried telling you 3 times now and your problem was exactly the same as from my first comment.

Comment: You seem very ungrateful for the help you're receiving, almost mocking me even for taking you literally after you're clearly asking a duplicate question that was answered and solved. Perhaps you should put more effort in finding a solution yourself, or at least trying out what people suggest before breaking them down.

Comment: Take a look at the MSDN tutorial again and see that all it does is set the row height by changing a TEXTBOX height, and setting the row to NOT grow vertically. If you take a closer look, you will also see that the article doesn't say how to prevent a row from growing HORIZONTALLY. Your solution does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution by myself. The RDLC report accepts HTML as Expression, so all you need to do is:

- Set a div with a fixed width inside the expression.
- Set the MarkupType as HTML

See how the report code changes:

**Before:**

```
<Paragraphs>
    <Paragraph>
        <TextRuns>
            <TextRun>
                <Value>=Fields!TextoCliente.Value</Value>
                <Style>
                    <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                </Style>
            </TextRun>
        </TextRuns>
        <Style />
    </Paragraph>
</Paragraphs>
```

**After:**

```
<Paragraphs>
    <Paragraph>
        <TextRuns>
            <TextRun>
                <Value>="&lt;div style='width:400px'&gt;" &amp; Fields!TextoCliente.Value &amp; "&lt;/div&gt;"</Value>
                <MarkupType>HTML</MarkupType>
                <Style>
                    <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                </Style>
            </TextRun>
        </TextRuns>
        <Style />
    </Paragraph>
</Paragraphs>
```

You can set the Expression in the Designer viewer to avoid having to deal with the replacement of '<' with '&lt', in that mode, you can just type <.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else finds this, there's a new answer in the possible duplicate link ([How to maintain long text inside RDLC report column ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32594761/how-to-maintain-long-text-inside-rdlc-report-column)) that appears to be actually correct, and simpler than the accepted answer here or there.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47495098/793387

Answer (score -1):

I've decided to add pictures in the answer to help explain exactly what needs to happen.

I'll follow the steps from the MSDN tutorial: [Change Row Height or Column Width (Report Builder and SSRS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239377.aspx) to first show how to set a fixed *height* and then show how to do the same thing to set a fixed *width*.

---

> **To prevent a row from automatically expanding vertically**
>
> 1. In Design view, click anywhere in the tablix data region to select
>      it. Gray row handles appear on the outside border of the tablix data     region. [image]
> 2. Click the row handle to select the row.  [image]
> 3. In the Properties pane, set `CanGrow` to `False`. [image]

---

> **To prevent a** ***column*** **from automatically expanding** ***horizontally***
>
> 1. In Design view, click anywhere in the tablix data region to select
>      it. Gray ***column*** handles appear on the outside border of the tablix data region. [image]
> 2. Click the ***column*** handle to select the ***column***.  [image]
> 3. In the Properties pane, set `CanGrow` to `False`. [image]

---

I sincerely hope this is detailed enough.

Comment: Tried this the first time you suggested that, it didn't work, I don't understand why are you insisting on a solution I already said that it didn't solve my problem, do I have to make a video of me doing that to you believe?

Comment: Let me explain: when you click on the Column, it does NOT select the Column itself, all it does is select all the textboxes inside that column. When you set CanGrow to false, it does not set the Column's CanGrow to false, all it does is set all the selected Textboxes' CanGrow to false. And this prevents the textbox from growing VERTICALLY only

Comment: First set the Column CanGrow on False then double check if the row CanGrow is sill on True, if its not set it on True. Then finally if you check the Column property again it should be empty. And that does work for me and  for the other guy who had the exact same problem.

Comment: The other guy didn't said the CanGrow solved his problem, it may be the LineBreak one that helped him. And I already tried your answer repeatedly. Are you trying to do this with strings coming from a dataset?

Comment: It baffles me that this doesn't work for you as it gives me no trouble. Perhaps your very detailed problem description isn't detailed enough. Whats version of Visual Studio are you trying this in and what framework are you building with? Maybe you should make a video showing exactly what you're doing, perhaps that way I'll be able to tell what you're doing wrong. There is still the second solution available to add break-lines at runtime. Calculate how many chars fit in the 400px based on your font style, size and the type of character, won't be easy I admit but it is a second very valid option